# Envio De form com Asp net mvc5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Bom dia, estou com um form para enviar onde o botão está fora do form, este formulário possui 50 campos distintos, fiz em html e preciso receber estes dados via post em um controller c#, porém não faço ideia de como receber estes dados, alguém pode me dar uma luz? não estranhem os inputs estarem contidos em uma tabela.

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++)
{
    if (i < 10)
    {
        <tr>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm justify-content-center row col-12">
                <td class="p-0">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size:19px" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; @i </span>

                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="p-0">
                    <input type="text" name="inputN_@i" class="form-control form-control-lg" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">


                <td class="p-0">
                    <input type="text" name="inputN2_@i" class="form-control form-control-lg" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
                </td>

            </div>
        </tr>
    }
    else
    {
        <tr>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm justify-content-center ">
                <td class="p-0">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size:19px" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">&nbsp;&nbsp; @i </span>

                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="p-0">
                    <input type="text" name="inputN_@i" class="form-control form-control-lg" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">


                <td class="p-0">
                    <input type="text" name="inputN2_@i" class="form-control form-control-lg" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
                </td>

            </div>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: Se você está utilizando MVC, seria interessante você utilizar um submit (botão) para ele postar o formulário.

Comment: infelizmente o cliente quer que o botão fique em outra parte da da tela totalmente fora  do formulário, para revolver isto pretendo enviar via javascript

Comment: Se o cliente pede... A solução porca e menos ruim na minha visão vai ser chamar um ajax que vai pegar seus campos na tela (serializando o seu formulário).

Answer (score 1):

Basta você disparar o `submit()` do form via javascript...

```js
let enviar = function(){
  document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
};
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
  <input type="text" name="teste" value="teste" /> 
  
</form>
<hr/>
<input type="button" value="Submeter" onclick="enviar()"/>
```